# grep regex to output only multiple matches on a single line

Tags: regex, grep, text-processing

I wanted to search for multiple matches in a single line and output only the matched words using grep

```
alias host='echo -e "Connecting to host   10.10.11.120\n===================";ssh root@10.10.11.120'
alias host1='echo -e "Connecting to host   10.10.11.121\n===================";ssh root@10.10.11.121'
alias host2='echo -e "Connecting to host   10.10.11.122\n===================";ssh root@10.10.11.122'
alias host3='echo -e "Connecting to host   10.10.11.123\n===================";ssh root@10.10.11.123'
```

I want grep to output only the host name and IP address like

```
host 10.10.11.120
host1 10.10.11.121
host2 10.10.11.122
host3 10.10.11.123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `grep` and `pcre`, required strings can be extracted

```
$ grep -oP 'alias \K[^=]+|@\K[0-9.]+' ip.txt 
host
10.10.11.120
host1
10.10.11.121
host2
10.10.11.122
host3
10.10.11.123
```

However, each extracted string would be in separate line, so one can use other commands to join them, for ex:

```
$ grep -oP 'alias \K[^=]+|@\K[0-9.]+' ip.txt | paste - -
host    10.10.11.120
host1   10.10.11.121
host2   10.10.11.122
host3   10.10.11.123
```

Or, a single `perl` command can also be used:

```
$ perl -pe 's/alias (host\d*).*@([\d.]+).*/$1 $2/' ip.txt 
host 10.10.11.120
host1 10.10.11.121
host2 10.10.11.122
host3 10.10.11.123
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -oP 'alias \K[^=]+|@\K[0-9.]+' ip.txt | paste - -
host    10.10.11.120
host1   10.10.11.121
host2   10.10.11.122
host3   10.10.11.123
```

this is great！

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` it could be much simpler, with your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F" |=|'|@" '{print $2,$(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting different field separators eg: space, `=` OR `@` for lines and printing 2nd and second last fields values for each line.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** using field separator and `match` function of `awk`. Set space and `=` as field separators AND use `match` function to get values needed by OP.

```
awk -F' |=' 'match($0,/root@([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){print $2,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution(Generic one):*** Adding pure Generic solution here, this will work irrespective of where `alias host` and `root@...` are placed in lines, in case anyone requires it.

```
awk '
match($0,/alias host[^=]*/){
  firstVal=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
  match($0,/root@([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/)
  print firstVal,substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` *matches*. It doesn't *modify*.

Try `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*ssh root@/host /' 's/'//' myscript.sh
```

Comment: actually i don't want to modify what's in the file. This solution will not work since i want to extract the hostname and ipaddress from the input. Not replace everything before "ssh root@" with host

Comment: @user6901586, since inplace editing option is not used, this command will not modify the input file itself... but the command given as such needs modification to avoid syntax errors and match expected output... something like `sed -E 's/alias (host[0-9]*).*ssh root@/\1 /; s/\x27//' ip.txt`

Comment: or `sed -E 's/alias (host[0-9]*).*ssh root@([0-9.]+).*/\1 \2/' ip.txt`

Comment: @Sundeep both the sed's will not work since you are using .* regex will not match anything after .* but the grep you mentioned works fine.

Comment: @user6901586 it works, I tested it before posting... may be extended regex option is `-r` instead of `-E` in your sed version.. `.*` is greedy but regex engine would try to match entire expression